# Нужен список URL закрытого сервера

Tags: http, url, веб-сайт, sitemap

Я работаю на закрытом сервере, мне нужен список всех доступных URL. Проблема в том, что карты сайта нет, файл robots я создать не могу, так как на сайт не мой, туда я захожу как рядовой работник. Возможно ли решить как-то эту проблему?

Comment: В общем случае невозможно, некоторые доступные URL могут быть скрыты извне, а ещё их может быть бесконечное количество (если они генерируются на лету по какому-то алгоритму)

Answer (score 0):

По моему, эту проблему нельзя решить "в общем виде", но можно предложить "достаточно хорошее практическое решение"

У кажого сервера есть файл логов доступа. Туда запиывается, с какого IP по какому URL пользователь ходил на сервер. В зависимости от используемого сервера расположение этого лога может отличаться, к примеру, в nginx (который служит "фронтом" для огромного кол-ва серверов) логи по умолчанию лежат в файле  access_log.

Я предлагаю взять какой то разумный периолд времени - неделю, месяц, полгода - и распарсить  access_log за это время. Как Вы увидите, у кажого URL (будем за URL счиать всё до параметров GET-строки) будет "счетчик популярности" - кол-во обращений к этому URL.

Дальше, в зависимости от задачи - можно или выбросить "непопулярные" страницы вообще, или использовать ранжирование по кол-ву обращений для построения "site map".

Comment: Здравствуйте! Дело в том, что мне это вряд ли поможет, ссылки эти в основном именно для меня, никто больше почти на них не заходит, на моем сервере они прописаны подряд, например http://сайт/freelancer/pdf/show?id_freelancer=&id=28674790
Потом следующая ссылка http://сайт/freelancer/pdf/show?id_freelancer=&id=28674791
То есть идет на единицу вверх , но не всегда, бывает большой пропуск в диапазоне 
я пробовал в ручную открывать все подряд, но сами понимаете, какой это кошмар 
может есть какие-то программы для анализа ссылок?

Comment: @user458279 тогда лучше просто получить доступ к базе данных (или попросить того человека, у которого доступ есть) и вытащить из неё список всех существующих id. Если же никак, то наверное единственным вариантом является полный перебор